# When two magnets are placed near then shouldn't the magnetic fore of the stronger magnet always be considered as the action force?

Tags: electromagnetism

> **We know that the force of attraction or repulsion depends on the strength of the magnetic field. If we increase the strength of the magnetic field, then the force of attraction or repulsion increases.**

Now suppose if we have two magnets $A$ and $B$ of which $A$ has a stronger magnetic field. So it will have more magnetic force and will attract or repel $B$ and similarly $B$ will also attract or repel A with equal and opposite force by Newton’s 3rd law of motion.

But if we consider first that $B$ attracts or repels with its magnetic force then $A$ will also attract or repel $B$ with that amount of force. So in the first case, the force of attraction or repulsion was more because $A$ having the greater magnetic force was the action force and for $B$ it was the reaction force but in the second case, it is less because the weaker magnetic force of $B$ becomes the action force and for $A$ it becomes the reaction force.

Does this mean to say that the above statement in bold holds true when we consider the stronger magnetic force as the action force and the weaker one as the reaction force?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call the two forces, i.e. which is the "action" and which is the "reaction". All that Newton's third law says is that they are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.

Comment: @Puk  Thnx for answering but I still don't get it. If magnet A first attracts or repels magnet B then this force is greater but if magnet B attracts or repels first then this force is weak because it has a weaker magnetic force and similarly, magnet A will also attract or repel with a weaker magnetic force by Newtons 3rd law. So if magnetic force has to increase then we should consider the stronger magnet's force attracting or repelling the weaker magnet first.

Comment: Neither magnet attracts/repels the other "first", the forces on both magnets are applied "simultaneously".

Comment: @Puk I know both forces act simultaneously but which magnet exerts the action force first the stronger or the weaker magnet. You need to say one as the action force only then we can say the other exerts a reaction force, right? So in all shouldn't the action force be of the stronger magnet which makes sense bcoz it will make the force of attraction or repulsion strong hence proving a stronger magnet exerts higher magnetic force in contrast to the weaker magnet which will lessen this force.